# How to kill a particular process(excel.exe) from command line?

Tags: command-line, microsoft-excel-2010

My command goes as below:

- `TASKKILL /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Microsoft Excel - Book1 Mine.xlsx"`

  This works fine but when I save the same as "Book1 Mine.xsl" and run the same command.
- `TASKKILL /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Microsoft Excel - Book1 Mine.xls"`

  It doesn't work.

When I manually opened the `Book Mine.xls` I see it's opened in compatibility mode. I guess the issue is here.

Question: How to kill a process (the one wiyh `Book1 Mine.xls`) which is opened in compatibility mode?

I use MS-Office 2010, Windows 7 OS 32 Bit

Any idea how to crack this?

Answer (score 8):

The below is the proper syntax to be used from command prompt to close various tasks:

- `taskkill /F /IM excel.exe`,
- `taskkill /F /IM iexplorer.exe`,
- `taskkill /F /IM notepad.exe`,

Where `/F` is used to kill the process forcefully.

In your example you have missed `IM`. Use spaces as shown in example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use wildcards to capture the difference...

eg;

```
TASKKILL /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Microsoft Excel - Book1 Mine.*" /f
```